# How to set SQL user password when deploying database project using CI/CD pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-devops, devops, database-project

I have database project (.sqlproj) in Visual Studio where I create user like this:

```
CREATE USER [MyUser] WITHOUT LOGIN; --I dont want to store password in source control
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_executor] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
```

I build dacpack in VSTS Build and deploy it to Azure in VSTS Release:
[image]

How do I setup the continuous deployment so that it will create user with password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Code88.AzureSQLLogin) plug-in in Azure Marketplace maybe useful.

You can also create logins using PowerShell and include conditional execution.

More alternatives explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884704/visual-studio-database-project-checking-if-sql-server-login-exists-before-creat).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder nobody mentioned  [SQLCMD Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386162(v=vs.100).aspx), which is the solution I ended up with